# Editing font styles in a Wordpress text area field using Custom Fields

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm taking my first steps coding. I took some courses on the internet and now I am building a Wordpress theme, so I can continue learning from this practice.

I'm using a plugin called Advanced Custom Fields to customize the content of my post types.

I'm defining a post type of interviews, which requires a bold font to the questions and a regular font to the answers.

I created a text area field with 3 formatting options:

[image]

It means that if I want to change font styles in the text area I have to select the "Convert HTML into tags" option and write the HTML tags. It's ok but it means that if I want to make a new line I would also have to write a `<br/>` tag, so I could expend hours only writing `<br/>` tags.

Is there a way I can automatically convert new lines into `<br/>` tags and choose font styles?

If I create a page, it gives me this panel that lets me choose font styles:

[image]

Why doesn't it exist in a post type? Is there a solution for this problem? Is it possible to change specific font styles in a text area field?

Comment: In this case it's probably easier to use the text editor and select what you want bolded and leave alone what you want non-bolded. Using custom post types probably won't help you here.

Comment: So there is a way to select specifically paragraphs of a text area using the text editor?

Comment: Yes but (not really) only by clicking and dragging then selecting the text editor style you want to apply that piece. Or you write html code in a code editor away from WP (I use Sublime) and use a find and replace function to do the multiple operations then paste back to WP.